# Typescript annotation preventing spread assignment

Tags: typescript

When I annotate `React.useState` with an interface or directly, then Typescript complains about spread notation assignment later in the file.

How do I keep the both the type annotation, the spread operation, but get rid of this static type checking error?

```
interface IInterval { name: string, id: number }

const [selectedInterval, setSelectedInterval] = React.useState<IInterval>();
// this doesn't work either
// const [selectedInterval, setSelectedInterval] = React.useState<{ name: string, id: number }>();
...
// errors here
<SomeElement onChange={(e) => setSelectedInterval({ ...selectedInterval, ...{ id: parseInt(+e.value) } })} />
```

```
Argument of type '{ id: number; name?: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<IInterval | undefined>'.
  Type '{ id: number; name?: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'IInterval'.
    Types of property 'name' are incompatible.
      Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
        Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.  TS2345
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a default value for `useState` to get rid of undefined property?

Comment: That did it. thx

Answer (score 0):

Since `selectedInterval` is defined to be either `IInterval` or `undefined`, here:

```
setSelectedInterval({ ...selectedInterval, ...{ id: parseInt(+e.value) } })
```

there is no guarantee that property `name` exists on `selectedInterval` (which may be `undefined`).

You need to make sure a property `name` with type `string` exists on `selectedInterval`:

```
        <SomeElement
    onChange={(e) => {
      if ("name" in selectedInterval && typeof selectedInterval.name === "string")
        setSelectedInterval({
          ...selectedInterval,
          ...{ id: parseInt(+e.value) },
        });
    }}
  />
```